# C++ How to convert char pointer array to string array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

In a C++ application, the arguments are all stored in a char* array, like so:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ...
}
```

However, a lot of people prefer the convenience of string manipulation, but it would be a hastle to have to convert every char* into a std::string every time. So my question is, how do convert a char*[] into a std::string[], so that you don't have to convert them all individually as you progress in your program?

Comment: Read the chapter on loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the arguments.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   std::string *s = new std::string[argc];
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        s[i] = argv[i];

}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you accept `std::vector`, you can use its range constructor.

```
std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);
```

Comment: That would be a `std::vector<std::string> args(...)`

Comment: @woolstar Edited. Thanks.